# Need circuit to Switch 240v a.c. mains with 3v or 5v

Tags: arduino, power-supply, mains, solid-state-relay, dimmer

I have the [IRFP460 power transistor](http://uk.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Vishay/IRFP460/?qs=zorda86t5M%252bnyKjlDVoLdg%3D%3D&gclid=CjwKEAiAo8emBRCX_OqU4qek6y8SJACzgf8fF1n7NTBYHRt_rVz0dpIc4t9MfPqcObovvn62jsA6ihoCikbw_wcB) 
which if I understand correctly can switch 20A/500V on 20v input.

I am wondering what a circuit design would look like that would allow me to either

(a) switch on and off a mains load, or,

(b) dim a mains load - light bulb - by varying the input voltage.

Comment: Sounds like you might 'shoot your eye out'...

Comment: Hi @SpehroPefhany ... I don't understand.

Comment: I am unsure whether you have the necessary skills to carry out this project safely. It is technically possible.

Comment: Your title doesn't match your question

Comment: @SpehroPefhany why don't U ask then ?

Comment: Hi folks, I didn't come here for prevarication. If U want to help I will gladly accept. :)

Comment: Hi @DoxyLover Title changed. Thanks for the heads up ! :)

Comment: A mosfet will only switch a uni-directional current -  if you really want to switch a mains load (AC) you should be looking at triacs triggered with opto diacs. Google solid state relay, zero crossing opto diac etc.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Can anyone help with a design"? Do you have a design of sorts already which you need some specific help with?

Comment: Hi Folks. Thank you for the helpful comments. I was involved in Instrumentation years ago and have forgotten everything, except perhaps safety. @JImDearden Thank you :) I will google that. Yes it is a mains A.C. 240v supply I wish to switch.

Comment: Hi @brhans. Thank You :) I have no design. I intend to get my first experience with Eagle by putting some sort of design on a board with tracks big enough to soak the current (unlike the sub-quarter micron Al tracks I once processed in the Lab long long ago - which I have forgotten everything about). I'm afraid I have a terrible memory. I am in the process of automating everything in my house and realised the only way to get a dimmer that does not buzz is to use solid state ?

Comment: Hi @JImDearden. Thank you :) Lots of designs coming up on your suggested Google search. Opto-Isolation a really nice equipment protection / safety feature. Thanks :)

Comment: Ty. By the way, welcome to the stack, please read the *do's and don'ts* of asking questions etc. it will save you a lot of grief. (down marking, barbed comments ...) Don't forget to accept the answer you think answers your question or up mark it if it has merit.

Comment: Hi @JImDearden :) Thank you. Life is too short for barbed comments .. where it's happy I tend to go :) Thanks for the Heads up Jim :) I will have a read.

Answer (score 2):

As Dwayne said, a solid state relay or SSR which uses MOSFETs could be used to safely switch mains voltages on and off. Dimming is another matter as most SSR's have poor response time. and before we get started: a zero cross SCR type SSR would be useless. So if your SSR uses SCR's then you can't dim it.

Also, what type of light are you looking to dim? Incandescent? LED? If it is fluorescent or compact fluorescent (CFL) then forget it. Though, there are dimming fluorescent ballasts that accept a DC voltage or PWM signal. And although I haven't personally ran across them, there are also dimming CFL's. Check your bulbs.

Going back a year or so I was looking at a data sheet for a MOSFET SSR and the maximum switching frequency was 500Hz. Though some might be higher or lower. The arduino has a pretty slow PWM frequency of about 500Hz. It might be possible to drive a faster SSR if it can handle the fast transients between turn on and off times. An 8bit PWM signal from an arduino can have a window as fast as ~8ns which might be too fast for an SSR to respond. This happens at high and low duty cycles as the on-off/off-on windows are very short. So low and high duty cycles might not work while medium duty cycles might.

Why are SSR's slow? They have basic gate drive circuits which cannot deliver enough current to the gates fast enough to quickly switch them on. This is also compounded by the fact that MOSFETs have a slight linear region at low gate voltages which will cause it to dissipate a lot of power when switched on slowly. Proper gate drive circuits use bootstrap caps and  power supplies to supply the necessary voltage and current to rapidly bang them on and off. SSR's don't have such circuits as they are designed for relatively slow ON or OFF use.

Building an SSR from MOSFETs is no easy task. The total current they can handle is a theoretical maximum before failure and you have to pay close attention to RDS-on which is the resistance of the drain to source terminals. A voltage drop there means power dissipation which means you have to pay close attention to your thermal design. And you also have to deal with isolation of the mains to the controller which gets a bit complicated. Switching large loads fast enough needs an isolated gate drive circuit and power supply. Usually an optoisolator between the driver circuit and the controller is sufficient for controller isolation. From there a gate drive chip can be used to switch the gates. Higher voltages might also employ a transformer after the gate drive chip to yet more circuitry to the gates. Transformer gate drives are typically found on large motor controllers and other high voltage systems that see peaks of 500+V.

If you are a newbie I would highly advise going the simple route and stick to ON and OFF control using an SSR. Dimming could be achieved using an off the shelf dimmer controller which accepts a PWM signal. A little google searching for "PWM light dimmer" would be a good start.

Comment: Hi @MisterTea. Thank you for your reply :) I can't quite believe I can remember nothing ! Years ago we used to grow our own epitaxial layers with MOVPE, implant with MBE and then I would pattern with electron lithography or a stepper to make interesting FET's. It was obviously too much for me because I felt like I had distinctly overdosed on technology when I left. Here I am years later putting a toe in tepid water and I can't keep up. Give me 1/2 and hour to read this and try to understand.

Comment: Hi @MisterTea. Thank you again :) .. I will break your very useful full response into paragraphs if I may ... :)

Comment: Paragraph 1. Yes I think the IRFP460 power transistor is a SCR/thyristor, incapable of switching A.C unless used as a pair or formed with a bridge of some sort. Triac poss/probarly better/easiear route ?

Comment: Paragraph 2. I have CFL lamps with low wattage ~11 watt or less bulbs. If switching these is difficult LED's will do. I have more and more of these. :)

Comment: Paragraph 3. Yes matching the 500Hz PWM of the arduino and its very fast insert of 90ns into each 500Hz frame window would require some matching to the SSR.

Comment: Paragraph 4. Slow SSR's are fine for me, if can be matched with PWM from Arduino or RaspPi :)

Comment: Paragraph 5. Yes. Not an easy task. Why I came here and asked for a simple design. Resistance of Drain to source important. Not taken for granted. Just not remembered. Easy to agree that : Thermal design and electrical isolation are very important for large loads. Opto isolator also important.

Comment: Paragraph 6. On/Off is ok except that I particularly need a SSR dimmer as the MK (potentiometer type) ones available here in the Uk are about the best ones available and they audibly buzz. It came straight back out of the wall switch and is waiting to be returned. The search terms U have given are very helpful :) I find every project takes ages so I will get going with this now .. hopefully when I am ready to move I will have everything I need :)

Comment: Thank you for your considered post. I remembered and learnt as I read over and researched the knowledge provided. Thank you :)

Comment: "Safe and simple AC PWM Dimmer for arduino / Raspberry pi", using a MOSFET, [Click here !](http://www.instructables.com/id/safe-and-simple-AC-PWM-Dimmer-for-arduino-Raspberr/?ALLSTEPS), www.instructables.com/id/safe-and-simple-AC-PWM-Dimmer-for-arduino-Raspberr/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: @Mister Tea - Oh, boy.  You have some seriously wrong information in your post.  Please consider this: most older theatrical lighting dimmer systems use a pair of large (sometimes VERY large) SCRs connected in reverse parallel to control lighting.  Your favorite rock band would have had racks of dimmers built this way when they went out on tour.  Bottom line: SCRs are indeed fast enough for phase-control dimming on standard 50Hz or 60Hz AC Mains.

Comment: @ Dwayne Reid - He is trying to dim using a PWM signal. The thrysisor method you mentioned can be used but not very effectively via PWM. The zero cross is when the SCR's shut off and that is too slow for effective PWM use. There are SSR's that employ MOSFETs so I figured I would steer him in that direction. Another problem he mentioned that I figured would come up: he wants to dim CFl's or LEDs. Zero cross dimmers are problematic for CFL's while LED's are fine.

Comment: @USER1062153 - You might want to look into using LED's and avoid CFL's. I have used them in dimmers but they use inductive  ballasts which are beaten up with the chopped up AC from a thrysistor dimmer. I have had both dimmers and lamps fail prematurely even if I did not dim them. A thrysistor system can be built but not using an SSR, your going to have to go discrete and use a PWM-> analog voltage -> voltage controlled zero cross dimmer using triac/SCR's. Also for kicks: how about a MOSFET inside of a bridge rectifier. source and drain across DC terminals and bridge AC in series with load.

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking at a commercially-available product known as a "Solid State Relay".  These are available in a wide variety of voltage and current ratings.  One popular manufacturer is Crydom but there are many other manufacturers to choose from.

Given the way you asked your initial question, I don't think that you have the necessary skill for this project.  However, I'll list a few of things that you might want to consider:

1) isolation.  How to you isolate your control signal from the lethal AC Mains supply?

2) The part number that you refer to is suitable for controlling only a single polarity of current.  That is: DC.  You need to do something else if you want to control AC.  The options for that might include using TWO of these devices *or* using a single device in conjunction with a bridge rectifier.  Or using a triac instead of a transistor.

3) Heat-sinking.  How do you safely isolate the power tab of your transistor from the metal heatsink that *IS* necessary?

Comment: Hi @dwayne-reid thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Hi @dwayne-reid. Thank you for your reply :) The whole "you don't have the skills thing" I am finding confusing. Why would I be here if I knew how to do this  ? I am asking for help, rather than asking ppl to tell me "don't do it".

Comment: Hi @Dwayne-Reid. Thank you for points 1 to 3 those are most helpful. Thank you :)

Comment: Hi Dwayne addressing ur points .. > 1 Opto-Isolation will protect the low voltage side from the high voltage side and add to safety, which I think is what u mean by lethal ? > 2 Thank you :) I had not realised (because I have forgotten all my electronics) that the device I have at hand (the IRFP460 power transistors, I have a pack of 5) can only control single polarity. So yes I could use (a)two of them or (b)single device with a bridge rectifier (c)triac. I would have to figure out how though. > 3 That is of particular interest to me, isolating the power tab and the NECESSARY heatsink.

Comment: Hi Dwayne ... yes point 3 is of particular interest. I would like to hear ur thoughts on isolating the heatsink from the power tab. Seller or manufacturer  suggests design takes this into account, but when I look at the device the pins are only 5mm or so apart. 500v? 20A? Yes safety here needs definite consideration. I would be interested to hear ur thoughts :)

Comment: @user1062153 - What scares me is that you don't appear to be aware of the dangers in what you want to do.  Thus my reluctance to give more detail.  What I'd suggest you do is take what you have learned here and spend some time with Google to see how AC Mains control is done SAFELY.  Once you have acquainted yourself with the dangers and have some awareness of how other people do this, please come back and ask away.  In other words, you need to do some homework.

Comment: Hi @Dwayne, Thanks for your comment :) I came here looking for a circuit design not a re-education in design principles. I could pick holes in your commentary too. For example I think U suggest that the circuit cannot be done with SCR type chips and yet it seems it is possible. The back biting all feels a bit precious !!!! All that is needed is a design. Thank you :) I will accept all help offered gladly :)